# Updating Strings in a Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm biting my teeth out here for hours now. I want to spell check all text values in a column of my data frame like that:

```
%%time
def correct_words(text):

    corrected_text = text

    misspelled = []
    words = spell.split_words(text)
    misspelled = spell.unknown(words)
    for uncorrected in misspelled:
        corrected = spell.correction(uncorrected)
        corrected_text = text.replace(uncorrected, corrected)
    return corrected_text

xtab['TEXTHOZU'] = xtab['TEXTHOZU'].map(lambda x: correct_words(x))
```

That function works just fine. But when the last line is executed, this is what I get:

```
[...]
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'", 'occurred at index TEXTHOZU')
```

I'd really appreciate your help, as I'm a novice to pandas.

Comment: What's ```spell``` in your code?

Comment: `
#pyspellchecker module

from spellchecker import SpellChecker

spell = SpellChecker(language=None, case_sensitive=True)

[...]

`

I takes a string and puts out a different, spell checked string.

Comment: Thanks for the question, @Grzegorz . It helped me find out I made the stupid mistake to assume all values in TEXTHOZU would be strings. They weren't.